# Explain code of Euler's method in numpy

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I am a python newbie trying to learn to solve differential eqautions with it numerically. I am learning it from this course: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/numerical-mooc/numerical-mooc/blob/master/lessons/01_phugoid/01_02_Phugoid_Oscillation.ipynb

and I am stuck on trying to understand what this code does:

```
for n in range(1,N):

    u = u + dt*numpy.array([u[1], g*(1-u[0]/zt)])

    z[n] = u[0]
```

if someone could just explain what this does I would appreciate it. Everything up to this point makes sense and I know this should just be Euler's method, but I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question. It (obviously) implements the function described in that web page. Which part exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Why are we multiplying dt by this array that contains g*(1-u[0]/zt) AND u[1]? What does u[1] do? And shouldn't the formula be u_(n+1) = u_n +... why can we just say u = u +...? And I don't understand why saving u[0] to z[n] stores the position. Why u[0]?

Comment: Because that is how the formula is defined? TBH the code is a bit "unclear", but it basically combined both formulas *(11)*  and *(12)* into a single line.

Comment: As for the rest: `u[1]` accesses the second element of the array `u` (basic Python and NumPy here), and the reason we can do `u = u + ...` is because you are reassigning the variable here to hold the next step. This is something that mathematicians have criticized about programming languages for some time and one of the reasons why functional programming has become more popular recently

Comment: Ok I think I finally understand it now after thinking about it, thank you for the help.